# Как посмотреть пошагово работу скрипта в отладчике?

Tags: javascript

Как отследить работу скрипта, чтобы он пошагово и понятно показал мне, как он работает?

Сначала я ставлю брекпоинты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом обновляю страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю пошаговое выполнение кода, а потом он выходит из него в другой файл со скриптом? Почему? Я же поставил брекпоинты в одном файле-скрипте, а он переходит в другой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если переходит в другой файл - значит на каком-то шаге происходит вызов функции, определение которой находится в этом файле. На панели есть кнопка, позволяющая перешагивать такие места

Comment: при пошаговой отладке можно использовать кнопки step over - перешагнуть или step into - зайти в функцию